# Reading object value from an array PHP

Tags: php, salesforce

I am trying to read the **Name** value from the following query result in php

```
$queryResult= 
QueryResult Object ( 
    [records] => Array ( 
                [0] => stdClass Object ( 
                      [Id] => [Account] => stdClass Object ( 
                                        [Id] => [Name] => Smith Joyn Household 
                                         ) 
                      [Amount] => 150 
                      ) 
      )
)
```

What I am using to print the values.

```
foreach ($queryResult->records as $record) {
   echo $record->Amount; // prints 150
   echo $record->Account->Name; // this doesn't
}
```

Comment: use `$record->Id->Account->Id->Name;`

Comment: Nope. Returns null.

Comment: Yes. And that doesn't work either

Comment: Give us a `var_dump($queryRecords);`

Comment: Oh... this worked $record->Account->Name

Comment: `$record->Account->Name;` That's what you stated in your question DOESN"T WORK!  Delete this.

Comment: Yes and I must have had it wrong in my code. I have requested this to be delete

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for the helpful nudge everyone. The following worked;

echo $record->Account->Name;

Comment: What?! Are you mocking us? in your question you wrote that it didn't work.